# Quoting a string in output from awk

Tags: linux, awk, csv, string

I am fetching a string from a file using  `awk` as shown below. Now I would like to double quote it. Any support would be highly appreciated.

```bash
awk -F',' '{print $(NF)}' sample.csv|  tail +2
```

output:

```
sample
```

Expected Output:

```
"sample"
```

Comment: You sure you want to use awk for processing files ending in .csv containing strings? will that work well with a row like `"Trick, Track and Trock", 12`?

Comment: It is unclear whether you want to quote the string under all circumstances, as CSV has its own quoting rules. If your data (which you don't show or say anything about) should be extracted as a quoted CSV field, then you should not be using `awk` but a tool that is CSV-aware.

Comment: @Kusalananda, Yes I want to quote this string under all circumstances

Comment: The word "Replacing" in the title of this question needs to change to "Placing". As it stands it is misleading.

Comment: @dhm I believe I have fixed this now, together with fixing some issues in the text itself. If the OP thinks I misrepresent their issue, they should update the question.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

To add quotes to the string, print it from `awk` with the quotes added:

```c
print "\"" $NF "\""
```

or

```c
printf "\"%s\"\n", $NF
```

Note that this would add quotes to already quoted fields.

Using the CSV-aware tool [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to extract the field with the header `Data`, quoted, without the CSV header:

```bash
mlr --csv --headerless-csv-output --quote-all cut -f Data file.csv
```

This would not add quotes to already quoted fields but would correctly return fields containing embedded commas, quotes and newlines, which `awk` would not be able to do easily.

---

To quote all data in a CSV file and to write the file back to the original file, I would use Miller like so:

```bash
mlr --csv --quote-all -I cat file.csv
```

The `-I` option causes `mlr` to perform in-place editing. You may also use `--quote-numeric` to only quote numerical fields.  Adding quoting in any other way does not make much sense, at least not if the data is read by a CSV-aware tool.  CSV processing tools generally *remove* unneeded quoting by default.

Comment: How to replace this variable with double quotes in the file ?

Comment: @user3777713 I'm not quite sure what you mean. Replace what in what file?

Comment: Replace the non quoted value with  quoted value in the orignal csv ile

Comment: @user3777713 You want to update the original file? This does not seem to be what the current question is about. The question asks about extracting a field and quoting it. If furthermore does not make sense to insert quotes in the CSV file as fields that need quoting already should be quoted.  If you have a _broken_ CSV file (fields that should be quoted are not quoted), then we need to see the actual data.